# Python search row for letters

Tags: python, search, row

I have a table of data that has a row of data as strings, but I am looking to convert the row to floats with this line:

```
uomorig_df['Conversion'] = uomorig_df['Conversion'].astype(float, errors = 'raise')
```

and it keeps erroring out, so I am thinking there is an alphanumeric character somewhere in just that row and I am hoping to identify that row, how can I find a letter in a row of data?

I was looking to try RegEx or Pandas... but kind of got lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a list comprehension, you can pretty easily loop over the indices and values of `uomorig_df['Conversion']` with `enumerate()`, convert the values to a string, and check if those values are valid floats with `.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit()`:

```
import pandas as pd

# example dataframe
uomorig_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Conversion": [1, 2, 3, 4, 'A', 6, 7, 8]
})

letters = [val for val in enumerate(uomorig_df['Conversion'])
           if not str(val[1]).replace('.', '', 1).isdigit()]
print(letters)  # => [(4, 'A')]
```

The result of the list comprehension is a tuple in the form of `(index, value)`, where `index` is the index of the alphabetic value in the row, and `value` is the nonnumerical value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but it sounds like you have something like:

"323849285293841852989841892485293849814198245985982305520234023528234**c**23234234234234"

with that "c" hidden inside and want to find that? Or want to make the string useful and filter out the "c"?

One simple way to get rid of everything but digits and '.' (I assume you want to keep '.' for floats - if not delete that +'.' part behind string.digits) is to use something like this:

```
float(''.join(filter(lambda x:x in string.digits+'.', your_input_str)))
```

If you are iterating over a number of rows and want to find the row which contains that "c", you can do something like:

```
import string

def find_alphas(rows):
    alphas = []

    for e,r in enumerate(rows):
        if not set(r).issubset(string.digits+'.'):
            for i, c in enumerate(r):
                if not c in (string.digits+'.'):
                    alphas.append( (e, i, c))
    print(alphas)


rows = ["2340285235823.234234#2a","25782392b234234.2?234"]

find_alphas(rows)

# result: [(0, 20, '#'), (0, 22, 'a'), (1, 8, 'b'), (1, 17, '?')]
```

Comment: I don't think OP has an row of long strings and wants to find the letter in all of those strings, but a row of short strings and just wants to know which of those short strings are invalid floats.